# Pool of machines without authentication?

Tags: ssh, authentication, cluster

I am working on a cluster of linux machines. What I need is for authentication to not be needed between the machines in this cluster, but required from outside.

I have considered the idea of setting up ssh keys between pairs of machines, but that would require n*(n-1) setups between n machines.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Actually youjust need only one private key/public key pair installed on every machine. This will make it work between servers. However that's security issue from my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

You can either set up an external authentication source such as a directory server with ldap and configure each machine to authenticate against that. Or like you said, configure ssh keys on each machine and then copy the keys over to each of the others.

Keys gets my vote unless your deployment is huge in which case centralised auth might be a good move in the sense of management and time saving.

Comment: I'd recommend that the OP just use something like Ansible to deploy keys around. ~15 minutes to write and test the ansible playbook, then ~1 minute to deploy to just about as many servers as one could imagine. :)